# Javascript "cannot read style property of null". Nothing is working

Tags: javascript

I have tried many other solutions on this problem but none of them are working. I checked my code from other questions I found and it seems to be perfectly fine.
I want the javascript to move the div called "snake" in what direction it is moving. But it keeps saying that snake is "null". Code:

Html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Snake</title>
        <style>
            #main {
                height: 100px;
                width: 100px;
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
            #snake {
                position: absolute;
                top: 20px;
                left: 20px;
                width: 10px;
                height: 10px;
                background: black;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main">
            <div id="snake"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```js
let movePos = null;
let isMoving = false;
let snake = document.getElementById("snake");

function main() {
    document.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
        if (event.key == "w") {
            movePos = "up";
        } else if (event.key == "s") {
            movePos = "down";
        } else if (event.key == "a") {
            movePos = "left";
        } else if (event.key == "d") {
            movePos = "right";
        }
        if (!isMoving) {
            askToMove();
        }
    });
}

function askToMove() {
    if (movePos != null) {
        isMoving = true;
        setInterval(move, 1000);
    }
}

function move() {
    if (movePos == "up") {
        snake.style.top = 100;
    }
}

main();
```

Comment: Do **not** do what Kevin George suggests in their answer. Instead, either move the script tag right before `</body>`, or leave it where it is and add `defer` attribute to the script tag.

Answer (score -3):

You've made the javascript run before the "snake" element is defined. Just replace your current HTML code with this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <body> <!-- Body shifted up -->
        <div id="main">
            <div id="snake"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Snake</title>
        <style>
            #main {
                height: 100px;
                width: 100px;
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
            #snake {
                position: absolute;
                top: 20px;
                left: 20px;
                width: 10px;
                height: 10px;
                background: black;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <!-- No Body Here -->
</html>
```

All I did was shift the body section up. I have had this same problem before and I fixed it with this.

Comment: `body` cannot occur before `head`, this renders the HTML invalid. Instead, either move the script tag right before `</body>`, or leave it where it is and add `defer` attribute to the script tag.